# DB2 add column, insert data and new id

Tags: db2

Each month, I want to record meter readings in order to see trends over time, and also want to add any new meters to my history table.  I would like to add a new column name each month based on date.

I know how to concatenate data in a query, but have not found a way to do the same thing when adding a column.  If today is 06/14/2018, I want the column name to be Y18M06, as I plan to run this monthly.

Something like this to add the column (this doesn't work)

```
ALTER TABLE METER.HIST
  ADD COLUMN ('Y' CONCAT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'YY') CONCAT 'M' CONCAT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'MM'))
  DECIMAL(12,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Then, I want to insert data into that new column from another table.  In this case, a list of meter id's, and the new column contains a meter reading.  If a new id exists, then it also needs to be added.

```
Source: CURRENT   Destination: HISTORY
                  Current           Desired
+----+---------+  +----+---------+  +----+---------+---------+
| id | reading |  | id | Y18M05  |  | id | Y18M05  | Y18M06  |
+----+---------+  +----+---------+  +----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 321.234 |  | 1  | 121.102 |  | 1  | 121.102 | 321.234 |
+----+---------+  +----+---------+  +----+---------+---------+
| 2  | 422.634 |  | 2  | 121.102 |  | 2  | 121.102 | 422.634 |
+----+---------+  +----+---------+  +----+---------+---------+
| 3  | 121.456 |                    | 3  |         | 121.456 |
+----+---------+                    +----+---------+---------+
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't physically add columns. Rather pivot the data on-the fly

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Adding columns is not a good idea. From a conceptional point and modelling point think about adding rows for each month. You have limited columns but more less unlimited number of rows and this will give you a oermanent model / table structure.